# Pulling API data into Django Template that has <a></a> tags embedded, is there a way of wrapping the text in an HTML tag?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I'm reading a very large API, one of the fields I need, have "a" tags embedded in the item in the dictionary and when I pull it into my template and display it, it shows the "a" tags as text.

exp:

```
"Bitcoin uses the <a href="https://www.coingecko.com/en?hashing_algorithm=SHA-256">SHA-256</a> hashing...  ...such as <a href="https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/litecoin">Litecoin</a>, <a  href="https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/peercoin">Peercoin</a>, <a  href="https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/primecoin">Primecoin</a>*"
```

I would like to wrap this in HTML so when it displays on the page it has the actual links rather than the 'a' tags and the URL.

What I'm looking to get: 
"Bitcoin uses the [SHA-256](https://www.coingecko.com/en?hashing_algorithm=SHA-256) hashing...  ...such as [Litecoin](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/litecoin), Peercoin, Primecoin*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I used the Humanize function with the |safe tag.

Pretty simple answer.

In the settings.py add 'django.contrib.humanize' to the INSTALLED_APPS:

**INSTALLED_APPS = [

'django.contrib.humanize', ]**

In the HTML Template add

```
{% load humanize %}
```

For the data you want to format use |safe

```
{{ location.of.data|safe }}
```

This will read the text as HTML.